# How to tell if linear programming dictionary is unbounded using ratios?

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

I don't really get how they got negative for the ratio 2/5. Is it because if they make $x3$ a leaving variable it'll become $x3$ = -5/2 + (3/2)$x1$? How does non-positive ratios make a problem unbounded?